# django auto slug in model forms like prepopulated-fields in django admin

Tags: django, slug, django-forms

is there a way to get the same results of using pre-populated fields in django's admin site for slug fields in a standard modelform

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well django is open source, so if you want to replicate certain behaviour you can [read the code](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django) and pick and chose what you like. For instance, you can see that contrib.admin uses a script called [urlify.js](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/admin/media/js/urlify.js) to do the dynamic slugging, with usage something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/admin-media/js/urlify.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("id_title").onkeyup = function() {
    var e = document.getElementById("id_slug");
    if (!e._changed) { e.value = URLify(document.getElementById("id_title").value, 50); }
}
</script>
```

... depending of course on where your admin media is served from (mine is from "/admin-media/")

Or if you're happy to do your slugifying in your view, you can use the function that's used in django.template as the slugify filter: [django.template.defaultfilters.slugify](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/template/defaultfilters.py#L222).

Comment: To bring up-to-date:

* Path for the admin javascript is `/static/admin/js/urlify.js` or in the template with the static template tag `{% static 'admin/js/urlify.js' %}`

* `URLify(s, num_chars, allowUnicode)` now allows for Unicode, so you need to add `true`/`false` to the URLify function call.

Comment: Also, will need to include an additional script `/static/admin/js/vendor/xregexp/xregexp.min.js`

Answer (score -1):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/media/js/urlify.js"></script>
```

```
var slug = document.getElementById("id_slug").value;

document.getElementById("id_name").onkeyup = function() {
    if (slug == '') {
        document.getElementById("id_slug").value = URLify(document.getElementById("id_name").value, 50);
    }
}
```